# Is there a way to output a sentence first then exit in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, game-development

I want to output some sentences when the user presses the wrong button and then exit using tkinter module (like says "idiot" or something) when they answer a question wrong and exit the process. However, `command=lambda:` only support only one action and the python interpreter will output an error when I add multiple lines. Is there any way to perform two or more actions for the windows made by tkinter?
This is part of the codes and I want the codes to output the self.correspondingBehavior part and then exit.

```
class Q3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="MCQ test!!! Question 3: Organic chemistry is the study of the compounds that "
                                "make up living organisms. All organic molecules contain:", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Carbon only",
                        command=lambda:self.correspondingBehavior('Wrong...check your '
                                                                   'notes and try '
                                                                   'again.'))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Carbon and nitrogen",
                        command=lambda:self.correspondingBehavior('Wrong...check your '
                                                                   'notes and try '
                                                                   'again.'))
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Carbon and hydrogen",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Q4))
        button3.pack()

        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=lambda: controller.destroy())
        button4.pack()
```

Comment: Simply create a new function and call whatever you want inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give more than one command (you can call more than one function) in command attribute using lambda. For this, you can use a list.

For example, `command=lambda:[root2.destroy(), next_step()]`

This would first destroy and exit the root2 window. And then also call next_step() function.

Comment: this is not suggested, it would be better to just define another function that calls them both instead of using lambda

Comment: It is like using ```def function1():``` and ```def function2():``` at the beginning and add different actions for both of them and use ```command: function1(), function2()```